Encoding issue while updating gdrive csv file using service API
I am trying to execute the following code, this code is essentially uploading a df having some sensor readings to csv file on the drive -
def update_csv_on_drive(creds, file_id, df):
    """Update an existing CSV file on Google Drive with a pandas DataFrame (using in-memory buffer)."""
    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        
        csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
        df = encode_columns_to_str(df, encoding='utf-8-sig')
        df.to_csv(csv_buffer, errors='replace', encoding='utf-8-sig')
        csv_buffer.seek(0)
        media = MediaIoBaseUpload(csv_buffer, mimetype='application/csv')
        
        updated_file = service.files().update(
            fileId=file_id,
            media_body=media,
            supportsAllDrives=True,
            uploadType="multipart",
        ).execute()

        print(f"Updated file ID: {updated_file.get('id')}")
        csv_buffer.close()

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred during file update: {error}")

I can weird character encoding when I open the file after it uploads on the drive, the degree symbol gets replaced with �. When I actually add a breakpoint and check df the col headers seem to be fine. Any idea how to resolve this? I have already tried changing the encoding type to a different values but nothing seems to work.

What about change the mimetype from application/csv to text/csv
